# localhost/phpmyadmin downloads inddex.php file - ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, php, phpmyadmin

I have install apache2, mysql and all the neccesary thngs and  then install phpmyadmin in my ubuntu 16.04.
It worked that day, but now, when I open localhost/phpmyadmin it downloads the index.php file.
it just not displaying the phpmyadmin page, but I am able to use the mysql database in my project.
just don't get it why this is happening.

Can anyone please help..!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a very common problem, and DuckDuckGo/Google is full of it. PHP is not activated, neither globally nor in the virtual host configuration. Modules and config loaded?

Comment: I have tried every solution from google, but no luck. localhost is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

As your PHP is obviously working on another virtual host, you may have the virtual host that delivers PHPMyAdmin bound to a single IP address (or hostname). The name `localhost` usually resolves to 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1 or their IPv6 equivalents, as listed in the file `/etc/hosts`. Make sure the virtual host configuration that is responsible for deliverying PHPMyAdmin also listens on localhost. The easiest way is to make it listen on *every* network interface.

To do so, change the headline of the virtual host configuration from

```
<VirtualHost myipaddr:80>
```

where `myipaddr` is either the IP address or the hostname, to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```